# complex service creation with ngTagsInput

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services, ng-tags-input

I am implementing [ngTagsInput](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/) with my blog so that when adding or editing new posts the users can add existing or their own tags to them.

My blog uses a firebase datasource which can be accessed via a factory:

```
 servicesModule.factory("postsDB", function($resource){
    return $resource("https://datasource.firebaseio.com/Posts.json", {
        id: "@id"
     },
     {
         update: {
             method: "PUT"
         },
         query: {
           method: 'GET',
          isArray: false }
    });
});
```

Because the ngTagsInput function needs to be used in other controllers I want to make it into a service as the Tags field is referred differently in order forms. The HTML looks as follows:

```
                           <tags-input ng-model="post.Tags">
                               <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>
                           </tags-input>
```

I want to create a service for ngTagsInput which references my other service above (`postsDB`). I have been trying this with the following code:

```
 servicesModule.factory ( 'AddTags' , function($scope, $http, postsDB) {
   var myTags = '';
    var myTags = $firebaseArray(postsDB.child('Tags'));

            function loadTags (query) {
                 return $http.get('/Tags?query=' + query);
            };
    });
```

And in my controller:

```
controllersModule.controller('AddPostCtrl', ["$scope", '$location', '$firebaseArray', '$sce', 'postsDB', 'AddTags',  function($scope, $location, $firebaseArray , $sce, postsDB, AddTags){
           AddTags(function(myTags){
             $scope.post.Tags = myTags;
           });
```

However, I am getting the following error:

`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- AddTags`

And it seems like it is not recognising the AddTags as a factory service. How do I get targettted `$scope.repeatevariable.Tags` to map to myTags key in the Firebase source?

EDITS - Throws Error:

```
ervicesModule.factory ( 'InputTags' , function($http, postsDB, $firebaseArray) {
  var myTags = '';
   var myTags = $firebaseArray(postsDB.child('Tags'));

           function loadTags (query) {
                return $http.get('/tags?query=' + query);
           };
   });
```

Comment: it is possibly because $scope is not available in services and factories as direct injection.

Comment: So how do you inject one inside the other?

Answer (score 0):

`$scope`is not usable within a factory. It makes no sense to use $scope within a factory. From the Angular docs: `Scope is the glue between application controller and the view.`

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that you do not even use $scope object in your factory. so just remove it from your factory constructor function dependencies and you are good to go.

Comment: Please see my edit above. I have removed `$scope` but now I am getting the following error:  "TypeError: postsDB.child is not a function". I am trying to access the child "Tags" of Posts>Post. which should return a JSON array "Tags" : [tag, tag1, tag2]. Am I doing this the right way?